# MVVM Visual Studio template installed but doesn't show up in template list

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, mvvm

I installed the [MVVM Visual Studio Template](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Model-View-ViewModel%20Toolkit).

It now appears in:

- Visual Studio C# Express 2008 (English)

but not in:

- Visual Studio 2008 (German)
- Visual Studio 2005 (German)

I reproduced this on another machine as well.

Has anyone been able to install the MVVM Visual Studio template **in a full version of Visual Studio in any language other than English?**

Answer (score 1):

We just created an MVVM template with Express, opened it in VS 2008, and did File | Export Template and now it shows up in the templates when we create a new project.